# How to use/link remote postgres db with django docker implementation

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

We have a remote postgres database(an amazon rds db) which we need to access from docker django application, how can we link the same ?

How my django-compose.yml should look in that case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Amazon RDS DB, but I guess you have an IP Address and some credentials to access the Database.

In that case you want to add the IP Address as an [extra host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/extra-hosts) to your Docker Container:

```
django_app:
  image: your_image
  extra_hosts:
    - "database:123.456.78.90"
```

Now your django-app can access the database with the hostname `database`.

Comment: this is basically exactly what i was refering in mysq question and actually only needed if you have no external DNS resolver - the external connection is still needed, its nothing "link" like

Comment: we would need to mention port as well(in ports section) ?

Comment: the `ports` section only specifies which ports are exposed to outside the docker-world (e.g. mapped to your external IP address).
In your case it's probably just port `80`

Comment: @Neo the easy answer is to always use the standard postgres port and just make that assumption. If you need a different port, you should specify that with an environment variable passed to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link those containers without a lot more effort like IPSEC in rancher or docker networks and other tools - and it is generally not needed. This would mean you would route / join 2 docker-networks of different docker hosts and thats a huge topic actually. The general theory behind this would be https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/ and i guess if you want this, try it and come back with more specific questions.

The low-level concept would be simply use external connections as is, since your docker container can access the out world without issues.

You AWS instance will for sure have a externally resolvable name, like youdb.aws.domain.com and the postgres server runs on lets say 9000

So what you do is, you just connect to `youdb.aws.domain.com:9000` with postgresql.